# Extracting data json python

Tags: python, json

I try parse json from that:

```
{
  "lastUpdateId": 78772216,
  "bids": [
    [
      "0.00000421",
      "133090.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000420",
      "345637.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000419",
      "84680.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000418",
      "127899.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000417",
      "175359.00000000"
    ]
  ],
  "asks": [
    [
      "0.00000422",
      "324731.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000423",
      "323497.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000424",
      "86010.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000425",
      "207321.00000000"
    ],
    [
      "0.00000426",
      "161378.00000000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

but always have some problem.

I try this:

```
from binance.client import Client
import json

api_key = "..."
api_secret = "..."
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)

depth = client.get_order_book(symbol='QKCBTC', limit=5)


file = json.dumps(depth, indent=2)


for i in file["asks"]:
    print(i[1])
```

Instead "dumps" i try dump, loads, load.

Errors:

dumps - TypeError: string indices must be integers;

loads - raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, ' TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict;

load - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'read';

dump - TypeError: dump() missing 1 required positional argument: 'fp';

Thanks for solution.

Comment: The errors are telling you that you have a dictionary - you don't need to deserialise from json because that has already been done.

Comment: You do not need to use `json.dumps` because you already have a dictionary. Calling `print(depth['asks'])` will print the list of lists of numbers.

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem ;D

Answer (score 0):

`json.dumps()` is a function that converts a `dict` object into a JSON string and returns it, so it returns a string object.

Now there are two cases,

1. If `client.get_order_book()` returns a dict, then you don't need to do anything to the data, you can just iterate over `asks`
2. If `client.get_order_book()` returns a json string, then you just need to parse it as a `dict` using `json.loads()`.